How can I map the same part of a texture to different parts of the model?
I am trying to model a simple hose-arm thing for a robot character, and am drawing all of the textures. These 3 sections on the model could be the same, though. They are modeled the same, and could have the same textures, so is there any easy way to just have all of them mapped to the same part of the uv texture so that I don't have to draw that part 3 times?

You should be able to hover over each UV island in turn, hit 'L' to select it, then Grab it and move it over one of the other islands  then paint all the islands at once. You may have to scale each one so that they fit over each other.

Thanks, although they don't quite line up just moving them over. I wanted to know if there was a good way to make sure the individual vertices lined up so the texture ends up the same on all three segments. Or if maybe there's a way to select them so that they all map to the same spot on the UV.

I'm not sure to be honest. I've never done much work on aligning UV areas. Not sure why the UV areas from your object aren't symmetrical. The object itself seems to be symmetrical. How did you UV unwrap it and have you added any seams to it to help the unwrap?

Because all 3 UV islands have exactly the same geometry you could use the Copy and paste tools in the UV editor to stack all 3 islands one atop the other.

In the UV editor, select the UV island that you want to copy (and transfer to the other two).
Open the UV menu and choose the Copy UV's option.
Select the other two UV islands.(select one then Shift select the other).
Open the UV menu and choose the Paste UV's option.

Now all 3 UV islands should be perfectly stacked.


That worked perfectly, thank you!
